# Mule ESB 3.6 User Authenticatication

Tags: api, authentication, mule, basic-authentication, raml

I'm implementing a web application with mule + raml + counchDB. It is working very well. But now I have to develop a authentication feature. To validate not only api clients, but users of this client. The goal is reach the same behavior of a normal Web application. The user call url, a login page is loaded ,user inputs username and password and is authenticated. After that for each request I have to validate user login and the url parameters to be sure he has rights to access information.

But I'm lost in how is the best way to do it or even if it is possible with mule. I've read about HTTP Basic Authentication, that I thing fits in what I need. But I could not realize if allows me to authenticate muof user and manager it to performe right validations.

Thanks for attention,
   Valter Gomes

Comment: Did you check http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+the+Spring+Security+Manager ? With this you can add Basic Auth to your endpoints. For an API, that could do it if you expose it over SSL.

Comment: Hi Dossot, thanks for reply. Yes I did it and works. But I not figure out how it exactly works. For example: I want to receive user and password then validate it against DB. Keep user information in memory, to validate next requests. Is it possible to mule CE version ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use EhCache or Hazelcast if you want a local or distributed cache to store info in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm using EhCache to control my user's information in-memory. But just are missing one point. I can't validate user against my counchDB (nosql) using spring security. Do you know a tutorial or doc which can help develop a custom Authentication Provider then access my nosql database?

Comment: I don't know of any, which doesn't mean there's none :D

Answer (score 0):

The enterprise edition of mule has an oauth 2 module that you can plug in your mule application. Please see http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+STS+OAuth+2.0a+Example+Application

There is no equivalent on the open source side, that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I'm using Community version and I don't know also.